# dismiss presentModalViewController not working over UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview

In my app I am using presentModalViewController and in the next controller I have used UIScrollView, also to dismiss presentModalViewController UITapGestureRecognizer is used

My code is like,

`UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnView:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self.fullScreenImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];`

```
-(void)tappedOnView:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

But it gives me an error

`attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <UITabBarController: 0xabb0610> modalViewController = <FullScreenViewController: 0xab5c440>`

So I replace the calling way like

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]) {
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // for IOS 5+
} else {
    [self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // for pre IOS 5
}
```

But the code doesn't work. I can't dismiss my presentModalViewController.
Without scroll view its working. What is wrong in above code?

Comment: Where is "-(void)tappedOnView:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {..}" implemented ? In which view controller ?

Comment: on next viewcontroller.

Comment: Well, from the error message you get, apparently self is a tabbarcontroller, so in order to dismiss the modal view controller, you need to get the current view controller in the tabbar. Try with [self.selectedViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; ?

Comment: I added it but nothing happens when I clicked. In my viewController I have added scrollView thats why I didn't get the current view controller is it right?

Comment: I dont know. Add more code please. Need to see how you create your view controller and how you transition between them.

Answer (score 0):

> tapGesture.delegate = self;

is not needed over there.

> [self.fullScreenImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

if fullScreenImageView is a scrollView then tapGesture already implemented over there. That might be the problem.